# Twig loops with mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, loops, twig

I'm building a php cms and using Twig template engine.
I'm now building the news archive page which shows page titles. Before Twig I would have done something like this:

```
$articles = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while ($article = $articles->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<a href=\"article.php?id=".$article['id']."\">".$article['title']."</a><br />"
}
```

How do I do that with Twig?

Comment: You need to send $articles to twig, then you can loop through in twig with something like :
{% for a in article %}
     <a href="">article name</a>
{% endfor %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html) this is a very simple stuff

**controller.php** from you will do business logic stuff (the *C* in *MVC*)

```
$articles = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$articles_data = [];

while ($article = $articles->fetch_assoc())
        $articles_data[] = $article

$this->render('html.twig', ['articles' => $articles]);
```

**home.twig** (the *V* in *MVC*)

```
..
...
{% for article in articles %}
    <a href="article.php?id={{ article.id }}">{{ article.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
...
..
```

You should also use a model class (the *M* in *MVC*) from which you will handle data example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc)

Happy coding :D